# Escaping text with jQuery append?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know that I can use `$.html` to set the HTML content of something, and `$.text` to set the content (and that this escapes the HTML).

Unfortunately, I'm using `$.append`, which doesn't escape the HTML.

I've got something like this:

```
function onTimer() {
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
           $('#messages').append(item);
        }
    }
}
```

...where the url returns an array of strings. Unfortunately, if one of those strings is (e.g.) `<script>alert('Hello')</script>`, this gets executed.

How do I get it to escape HTML?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Check out how jQuery does it:

```
text: function( text ) {
    if ( typeof text !== "object" && text != null )
        return this.empty().append( (this[0] && this[0].ownerDocument || document).createTextNode( text ) );

    var ret = "";

    jQuery.each( text || this, function(){
        jQuery.each( this.childNodes, function(){
            if ( this.nodeType != 8 )
                ret += this.nodeType != 1 ?
                    this.nodeValue :
                    jQuery.fn.text( [ this ] );
        });
    });

    return ret;
},
```

So something like this should do it:

```
$('#mydiv').append(
    document.createTextNode('<b>Hey There!</b>')
);
```

**EDIT**: Regarding your example, it's as simple as:

```
$('#messages').append(document.createTextNode(item));
```

Comment: Thanks! Now I know jQuery doesn't have any equivalent to document.createTextNode()

Answer (score 9):

You're appending an element which already has content?  Or you're adding the content after you append?  Either way, you still need to do .text(...) on that element.

If you're using append and passing HTML as the argument, then try creating the element first, and passing it to append.

Ex:

```
$('<div/>').text('your content here').appendTo('div#someid')
```

Comment: Won't this wrap the text in a DIV? I can't see how that would be desired most of the time.

Comment: That works, but it seems a bit clunky. Do you want to throw in an explanation of how it works and why I'd want to use it?

Comment: Aha. I start to see it. It doesn't seem that you can open a tag -- i.e. $('#x').append('<strong>'); and close it again later. You seem to need your scheme.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to get jQuery to escape some text to an HTML fragment and don’t want to touch `document` directly yourself, the following pure jQuery can escape text to HTML for you (but only in an HTML context):

```
jQuery('<p/>').text('v & M_FLAG == M_FLAG').html()
```

This can be used to append text quite inefficiently:

```
jQuery('#message').append(jQuery('<p/>').text(item).html());
```

There will be no extra `<p/>` element inserted because [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html) returns the HTML-formatted contents of an element, excluding the element itself.

Based on jQuery’s lack of a built-in way to instantiate text nodes, I think jQuery’s authors expect users to directly use `document.createTextNode()` as shown in an [earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/944456/429091).