# jQuery append text

Tags: jquery, html, css, append

I want to append some simple data in a div like:

```
$('#msg').append('Some text');
```

In the  body, i think i will need to place the the html like.

```
<div id="test">    

<div id="msg"></div>  //show text inside it.

</div>
```

However, I want to add some CSS to the `#msg`. For example, background color. Now the problem is that, since the `#msg` div is present all the time, i see the  background color even when the text is not appended to it. I have tried to add css like "display:none, but in that case i can not see the text appended to it.
Can i do it so that the `#msg` div appears inside the `#test` only when the text is appended to it? Thanks.

Comment: OP, please consider changing the answer from Hendy Irawan to be the accepted answer.

Comment: This post seems to contain two different questions: 1) How to append text to a `<div>` and 2) How to hide the `<div>` until the text has been added.

Answer (score -17, accepted):

```
$('#msg').append('Some text').show();
```

Comment: Thanks. This works but just wondering how? The #msg div remains in the html, but how it doesnt apply the css unless the jquery uses show?

Comment: @sunjie -- `show()` just removes the `display: none` and turns it to `display: block`

Comment: This does not append text, it appends HTML. Big difference.

Comment: Agree with @usr. If the "text" is coming from user input, this will cause JavaScript injection.

Comment: Would `$('#msg').text( $('#msg').text() + 'Some text' )` be safer? According to the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text2), `.text( [text] )` escapes the text with `.createTextNode()`.

Comment: Don't know why people are ranking negative to your answer.
You have answered correctly.

Answer (score 178):

The proper way to append **text** (constrast with appending **HTML**) would be:

```
var someText = "Hello, World!";
$('#msg').append(document.createTextNode(someText));
```

If `someText` is coming from user input or anything else, it will be properly HTML-escaped. Which should prevent [JavaScript injection, the 3rd most common web security vulnerability in the world](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-Top_10).

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/944456/122441

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Thanks for posting this along with the explanation of *why* it's the correct way to safely append text to an element.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use

```
$('#msg').html('A styled <span style="background: yellow">paragraph</span>');
$('#msg').show();
```

Escape when needed.

Comment: The method .html() does replace the existing content by new one. I think the questioner was not aware there is a tiny and important difference between replacing and appending.

Answer (score -1):

I know this question has been answered with different variations but here is one more. I had a similar requirement so spent a little time trying to find a way to do it.

**If** you know the structure of a HTML, you can get the contents **as HTML** using jQuery, next change the contents of the same HTML by adding to it.

```js
var lastPageText = $('#test p').html();
        $('#test p').html( lastPageText + ' &#128578;' )
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="test"><p>This is how things go perfecting well<span> even in a span</span></p></div>
```

Hope the above helps someone looking for similar answer

Cheers

Comment: that's the exact definition of append IMHO

Comment: I never said this is the best way it's another way if someone wants to try. Sometimes you have a platform element you can't change.

Answer (score -5):

You can do this using multiple ways. You can create a css class and do this:
**Method 1**
CSS:

```
.hello{ background-color: green }
```

HTML

```
<div id="msg"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#msg").append("hello world").addClass("hello");
```

**Method 2**
HTML

```
<div id="msg" class="hello" style="display:none;"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.hello{ background-color: green }
```

Javascript:

```
$("#msg").append("hello world").show();
```

**Method 3**
HTML:

```
<div id="msg"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#msg").append("hello world").css("background-color","green");
```

Comment: @AliKhanusiya Because .append() appends HTML and not text.

Comment: @AliKhanusiya You maybe need to read it too: "content: DOM element, array of elements, HTML string, or jQuery object to insert at the end of each element in the set of matched elements."