# I would like to append anchor text between a tags using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to append an anchor text in an a tag using jquery. Normally I can make an a tag look like this

```
<a href="#" >Hey</a>
```

and Hey is the anchor text. But what I want to do is just have

```
<a href="#"></a>
```

and then use a javascript file running in the background append Hey as an anchor text to that link. How can I get that done?

**EDIT**
This is what I tried to do but it didn't work.

```
$('hey').appendTo('.chat');
```

Where chat was the class name of the a tag.

```
$('<p>Hey</p>').appendTo('.chat');
```

That didn't work as well.

But thanks anyway guys. This code works

```
$('.chat').html('Hey');
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: And where does this text come from? Should *every* `a` element have the same text?

Comment: *Questions asking for code must demonstrate a **minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Tell us what you've tried to do, why it didn't work, and how it should work. See also: [**Stack Overflow question checklist**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)*. Possible dupplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588630/jquery-append-text http://stackoverflow.com/questions/841722/append-text-to-input-field/6885854#6885854

Comment: I tried a few things like $('Hey').appendTo('a'); but it didn't work.

Comment: This is some important information that needs to be put inside the question! Here is [**the official documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) with `$.appendTo()`. It probably didn't work because `'a'` is a string, not a `DOMElement`, and that the string that you wanted to add is not inside an element, so it's only a `textNode`. ***EDIT:*** [**Here is a working example of what you have tried**](http://jsfiddle.net/DWBY7/) and that **should** work. Your HTML element is probably declared the wrong way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seeing that you tagged jQuery in the question:

```
$('a').html('Hey');
```

Comment: And why are you using `html()`, as opposed to `text()`?

Comment: @DavidThomas Out of habit I guess, I normally only use `.text()` for retrieving a value. In this case it would be acceptable to use it to set the value too.

Answer (score 0):

Give your anchor tag an id (assuming you want to add "hey" to a specific anchor) and then simply append with jQuery.

like so:

**HTML**:

```
<a href="#" id='link1'></a>
```

**jQuery**:

```
$("#link1").append("hey");
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript

```
var anchor = document.getElementById('something');
anchor.innerHTML += "some text";
```