# How to append/prepend/create a text node with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Escaping text with jQuery append?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944436/escaping-text-with-jquery-append)

My HTML is somewhat like this:

```
<div id="selector">Hello World</div>
```

Now I'd like to append some text to this div. I know that I could simply use

```
$('#selector').append(text);
```

but this wouldn't escape any special characters in `text`. Another way is to wrap the text in a span:

```
$('#selector').append( $('<span>').text(text) );
```

But this is ugly, because it creates unnecessary markup. So my current solution is to manually create a TextNode:

```
$('#selector').append( document.createTextNode(text) );
```

I was wondering whether there is any *jQuery-style* way to do this?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The `createTextNode` approach is probably the best way to go. If you want to have a jQuery-ish syntax, you could make a plugin.

```
$.fn.appendText = function(text) {
    return this.each(function() {
        var textNode = document.createTextNode(text);
        $(this).append(textNode);
    });
};
```

Comment: +1 All of the other provided methods *overwrite* the current contents of the container element, which may cause event listeners and DOM properties to disappear/reset.

Comment: @lonesomeday hehe that's a neat easy to use plugin

Answer (score 3):

[$.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) accepts also a function as parameter. This function will receive an index and the current text. The return value of the function will be set as the new text.

> `.text( function )`
>
> **function**
>   Type: `Function( Integer index, String text ) => String`
>   A function returning the text content to set. Receives the index position of the element in the set and the old text value as arguments.

```js
$("li").text(function(idx, txt) {
   return txt + " <item>";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a good idea. But unfortunately any elements inside the container get overridden, see the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4SvgV/2/

Answer (score -3):

You can use;

```
$.extend({
        urlEncode: function(value) {
            var encodedValue = encodeURIComponent(value);
            encodedValue = encodedValue.replace("+", "%2B");
            encodedValue = encodedValue.replace("/", "%2F");

            return encodedValue;
        },
        urlDecode: function(value) {
            var decodedValue = decodeURIComponent(value);
            decodedValue = decodedValue.replace("%2B", "+");
            decodedValue = decodedValue.replace("%2F", "/");

            return decodedValue;
        }
});
```

to escape HTML characters before you append to the DOM.

Use it like; `$.urlEncode(value)`

Using it; `$('#selector').append($.urlEncode(text));`

**Update #1**

You could this `$('#selector').html($('#selector').html() + text);`

I suspected this was what you wanted.

Comment: This works, but isn't what I actually was looking for: If my text is `<b>Strong</b>` it should display exactly this. Your code produces: `%3Cb%3EHi%3C%2Fb%3E`

Comment: Thanks for the update, but actually this doesn't work as well. Now it would display **Strong** but I would like to display `<b>Strong</b>`.

Comment: To solve this problem with escaping the text, you definitely want something like PHP’s [`htmlentities()`](http://docs.php.net/htmlentities), not `encodeURIComponent()`. Perhaps `jQuery('<span/>').text('people & humans').html()` instead of `$.urlEncode('people & humans')`.