# Twitter API - no encoding

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, api, encoding

I'm currently working on a project for university. we are trying to use the twitter api but we are having some trouble with the query. I want to search a complete string, therefore I need to put my string in quote sings.( like "I'm seraching for this whole sting")
the problem is that the command I use to get the array from twitter somehow encodes the whole string but I need the quote sings to not be encoded. I hope you guys understand my problem. in addition i'll post my js code.

JS CODE: first I tryed a json command but it didnt work. afterwards I tryed ajax but I ran into the same problem. I don't get a response when I use quote signs in my query.

```
$( document ).ready(function() 
{
console.log("ready");

// div mit id unique1 - bei klick mache onClick1
$('a#unique1').bind('click', onClick1);
});


function onClick1(elem)
{
var inputString = $("#SearchInput").val();
var EncodedString = encodeURI(inputString);

console.log('test' +  inputString); 

var endNode = 'search/tweets.json?q=hate%20' + EncodedString + '&result_type=mixed&count=200';


/*
$.getJSON('twitter/twitter-proxy.php?url='+encodeURIComponent(endNode), 
*/

$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: 'twitter/twitter-proxy.php?url='+encodeURIComponent(endNode),
            data: " ",
            success: function(twitterResponse){

                var respStr = "start";


                console.log(twitterResponse);
                console.log(twitterResponse.statuses);

                for(var i = 0; i < twitterResponse.statuses.length; i++)
                {
                    $('.container .apiCall ol').append('<li>'+ twitterResponse.statuses[i].created_at + '</br>' + twitterResponse.statuses[i].text.toLowerCase() + '</li>');

                    respStr = respStr + twitterResponse.statuses[i].created_at + twitterResponse.statuses[i].text.toLowerCase();


                } 

            }           

});

/*
function(twitterResponse)
{
    var respStr = "start";


    console.log(twitterResponse);
    console.log(twitterResponse.statuses);

    for(var i = 0; i < twitterResponse.statuses.length; i++)
    {
        $('.container .apiCall ol').append('<li>'+ twitterResponse.statuses[i].created_at + '</br>' + twitterResponse.statuses[i].text.toLowerCase() + '</li>');

        respStr = respStr + twitterResponse.statuses[i].created_at + twitterResponse.statuses[i].text.toLowerCase();


    }
    */


    /*

    // respSgtr = "  ";

    // write tweets to file          
    $.post("writer.php", { fileString:respStr},
    function(response) 
    {
    //alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
    }); 



});*/
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is flawed.

- jQuery does all the parameter encoding for you. Don't interfere, just pass an object which contains keys and values. Do not build URLs from individual bits of string.
- Important security consideration: Don't build a server-side proxy script that accepts any arbitrary URL. Doing this is plain stupid.
- Instead change your PHP script to accept a set of `operation` verbs, like `"search"`, which are hard-wired to the correct URL on the server side.
- I recommend using `$.get()` and `$.post()` over `$.ajax()`, for the benefit of cleaner code.
- Further, use `$.each()` rather than a regular `for` loop. The resulting code will be cleaner and easier to read.
- Avoid building HTML from bits of string. Especially if the bits of string come from a completely untrustworthy source, like Twitter. Use jQuery's capabilities and the DOM to build HTML safely. (read about XSS vulnerabilities if you're not sure why I bring this up)

Suggested solution (`appendText()` jQuery plugin taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7619739/)):

```
$.fn.appendText = function(text) {
    return this.each(function() {
        var textNode = document.createTextNode(text);
        $(this).append(textNode);
    });
};

$(function () {
    $('a#unique1').on('click', function (event) {
        $.get('twitter/twitter-proxy.php', {
            operation: 'search',
            params: {
                q: 'hate ' + $("#SearchInput").val(),
                result_type: 'mixed',
                count: 200
            }
        }).done(function (twitterResponse) {
            $.each(twitterResponse.statuses, function (index, status) {
                $("<li>")
                    .appendText(status.created_at)
                    .append("<br>")
                    .appendText(status.text.toLowerCase())
                    .appendTo(".container .apiCall ol");
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: i'm actually searching for phrases.
there is a bug report in the twitter api forum but its from 2 years ago. hopefully this explains my problem a little bit more in detail.
https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/1114

Comment: Okay but that's a Twitter API issue (if it is one), not an URL-encoding, Ajax or jQuery issue. My answer is strictly about the client side only. How Twitter itself expects or deals with search requests I cannot say.