# How to create text node using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

What is the best way to create new text node and append it to the DOM?

I'm currently using this:

```
$('#someDiv').append(document.createTextNode('Some text'));
```

but is it the best way? Are there any other alternatives?

**UPDATE**

after checking the jQuery code I found that my variant probably the best...

here is how `.text()` function implemented in jQuery:

```
text: function( value ) {
    return jQuery.access( this, function( value ) {
        return value === undefined ?
            jQuery.text( this ) :
            this.empty().append( ( this[0] && this[0].ownerDocument || document ).createTextNode( value ) );
    }, null, value, arguments.length );
},
```

so, `.text()` function calls `.createTextNode()` method, so if you wish to save on calling extra operations, it's better to use direct text's node `.append()`

Comment: I would say this is the best way

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7619739/how-to-append-prepend-create-a-text-node-with-jquery and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/944436/escaping-text-with-jquery-append

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Like this :

```
var yourtext = 'Some text';
$('#someDiv').append(yourtext);
```

Comment: `.append()` processes the arguments as HTML, thus not escaping characters like `&` and `<`.

Comment: As some others have stated in the comments, he said nothing about escaping the content, only to "append" text to the DOM. But thank you for the note.

Comment: Appending text just isn't the same as appending raw HTML code. Your and Alex' examples work well, but you can't say the same in the general case.

Comment: Dangerous answer.  In a real-world app, _yourtext_ is probably coming from a database or HTML form submission, not a constant string.  If you just use .append(), you're begging for an HTML injection attack.  Never get in this habit, even if you're starting with safe string constants, because the next coder could replace the constant with something else, not knowing that you didn't bother to escape the value when you rendered it.

Answer (score 3):

It's as simple as using [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

```
$("#output").text("Hello, World!");
```

Comment: why do you think it's better then my example?

Comment: For compactness and ease this is good, for efficiency use @AlexWheat's method.

Comment: This technique will also destroy the existing contents (a.k.a. children) of the `#output` node.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's what you're looking for

To get rid of all the text within that `<div>`

```
$('#someDiv').html("Some Text");
```

To append text to it

```
$('#someDiv').append("Some Text");
```

To prepend ...

```
$('#someDiv').prepend("Some Text");
```

EDIT

With this string "Some text" .html() and .text() would render the same.

.text() will not escape special characters

```
$('#someDiv').text("<b>Hello</b>");
==> <b>Hello</b>
```

.html() will

```
$('#someDiv').html("<b>Hello</b>");
```

==> **Hello**

Comment: That wouldn't escape characters like `&` and `<`.

Comment: why to use .html() if for text better to use .text()?

Comment: "jQuery.html() treats the string as HTML, jQuery.text() treats the content as text."
source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910794/what-is-the-difference-between-jquery-text-and-html

Comment: I know what is the difference between html() and text() :), I mean I don't need HTML... the question about plaint text only... I usually prefer to build HTML using .appent(), .appentTo() and others

Comment: ha ok :) well if the question is how to append text to the DOM .. I would just do `$("body").append("text");`

Comment: no, the question was is there better way to add text node to DOM. And using .text() not better... it's simpler, but not better...